# Atom fails coloring string elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, atom-editor, text-coloring

I'm currently working a project in Atom where I want to declare an array of strings, but unfortunately atom fails coloring them after a certain amount of elements inserted.
When logging the lengths everything run smoothly without getting any error message.
Any suggestion?
[image: Array coloring failure]

Comment: So everything works? If you don`t have console errors then it must be a bug from the text editor. Atom is "hackable" maybe you can patch the error :P

Comment: Thanks for answering I'll post it!

Answer (score 1):

Atom only tokenizes a certain number of tokens per line (currently set to 100 [in grammar-registry.coffee](https://github.com/atom/atom/blob/d79690e2d586dbe4a0a6ace4be1b675a4b11b03f/src/grammar-registry.coffee#L18)) in order to prevent performance issues with long lines. See [atom/atom#1667](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/1667) for more.